# Declare a variable inside a functional component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have a variable "myVar" (NOT A STATE)

```
const myComponent = () => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(true)
  const myVar = false

  return <button onClick={() => {myVar = true} >Click here</button>
```

}

As you know, this way, if an other state change, the component is re-render, then "myVar" is re-initialized...

Below, solutions I found...

SOLUTION 1 : Initialise the variable outside of the component (but not in the component scope)

```
const myVar = true
const myComponent = () => {
  ....
}
```

SOLUTION 2 : declare a component prop (but public)

```
const myComponent = ({myVar = true}) => {
  ....
}
```

What is the regular solution ?

Comment: In your case `ref` works perfectly.

Comment: You can use `useRef`. Read more [here](https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/use-useref-hook-to-store-values-you-want-to-keep-an-eye-on/#create-references-for-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook. The value stored by the reference will not be reinitialized during a re-render. Changing the value stored by the reference will not trigger a re-render, as it is not a state change.

Comment: Tank you. Yes, the goal is to not trigger "useless" re-render.
I will use useRef, but I find that not conveniant to have to call the '.current'

Comment: My question was in the doc : 
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in a class component, this can be resolved by the **componentDidMount** & the **componentDidUpdate** logics. Same behavior can be done with functional component by using the **useRef** & the **useEffect** hooks:

```
const myComponent = () => {
      const mounted = useRef();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!mounted.current) {
           // do componentDidMount logic
            mounted.current = true;
            const myVar = false
        } else {
          // do componentDidUpdate logic
        }
      });
    }
```